# CSS div using 'position absolute' hides content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a corner button display new content on hover using the following setup:

```
<div class="panel panel-default1">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class='amg-corner-button_wrap'>            
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="overlay-content">
                <h2>Image Ink Logo</h2>
                <p>Logo for a screen printing company. They wanted a detachable/recognizable brand that didn't need the name of the company.</p>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- wrap -->
    </div> <!-- panel body -->
</div> <!-- panel default -->
```

CSS:

```
.panel-default1 {
    padding-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap .overlay {
    border-bottom: 40px solid #e8c63d;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: .95;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    width: 0;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover .overlay {
    border-bottom: 800px solid #e8c63d;
    border-left: 800px solid transparent;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.amg-corner-button_wrap .overlay-content {
    bottom: 0;
    color: #333;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.amg-corner-button_wrap .overlay-content h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    padding: 0 0 12px;
}
.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover .overlay-content {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
```

Here is fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ar3jkuvq/

The hover deployment works well but the `.overlay-content` text does not show up if `.amg-corner-button_wrap` uses `position: absolute`. However I need it to keep the hover on the wrap only.

How can I keep the hover effect on the wrap only and show the text content at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `transform` property to scale the overlay instead of using a border, and then use a *General sibbling combinator* [[w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators)] selector `~` to select the `.overlay-content` element that is preceded by a `.amg-corner-button_wrap:hover`.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpf5nypp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

add this class in your css

```
.amg-corner-button_wrap{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make use of the `pointer-events` attribute here.

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.amg-corner-button_wrap`

Add `pointer-events: none;` to `.panel-default1`

Add `pointer-events: all;` to `.amg-corner-button_wrap .overlay`

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59h4c884/)